# Why does phpMyAdmin display an error with this setup?

Tags: linux, unix, apache-http-server, php, mysql

Trying to setup phpMyAdmin for the first time with MySQL.

I just created the config script with the wizard as follows:

```
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'http://server_name_here.edu';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '10021';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/home/user7/mysql.sock';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'mypassword12345';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['order'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['rules'] = array();
```

When I go to run the main php admin index page I get the following error:

> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
>   rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
>   password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server. Error
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>   2005 - Unknown MySQL server host 'http' (1)

Any point in the right direction is very helpful.

Thank You.

**EDIT**

removed the http:// prefix from the server name -

> phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
>   rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
>   password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
>   the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server. Error
>
> MySQL said: Documentation 2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server at
>   'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 99

Comment: what distribution of linux are you running? Is mysql started `ps ax | grep mysql`?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `http://` from the server hostname. MySQL doesnt use http for connections.

<strike>Also MySQL uses port `3306` not `10021`.</strike>

Comment: even if I changed the port number during installation? i.e. - setenv MYSQL_TCP_PORT 10021

Comment: remove http:// as a first step.

Comment: @Greg McNulty the hostname cant have `http://` prefixed to it, it just wont work however your port might be different (Generally its 3306.)

Comment: All I removed the http:// prefix, however, now the index page sits there forever and then times out....?

Comment: check your logs ... `tail -fn30 /var/log/mysql/error.log` or something like it.